# How can I add checkbox in datalist in jsp or html5

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to add checkbox to each element of **datalist**(new element of HTML5) in jsp or html5.
I will fetch like, list of names from database and then I want all names in datalist with checkbox(something like dropdown list with checkbox).
So how can I do this , please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use plug-ins, see if this link http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it out of the box.

> Identifies a list of pre-defined options to suggest to the user. The
>   value must be the id of a  element in the same document. The
>   browser displays only options that are valid values for this input
>   element. **This attribute is ignored when the type attribute's value is
>   hidden, checkbox, radio, file, or a button type.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox